# Convert date string to a date object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Getting the date from the user and storing the value as a string variable. The value looks like this **Fri Aug 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

I want to convert that string again into a new Date() object for further configurations (I need to add the number of days to the selected date and show it on another Angular mat-datepicker)
How can I do this..?

Comment: Bit of general advice about dates - never store them as a string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast a date string directly to a Date object like:

```js
let myDate = new Date("Fri Aug 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
```

You can manipulate your date as follows:

```js
// For instance adding a day:
let today = new Date("Fri Aug 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");

let tomorrow = new Date()
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this but doesn't seem to work when I put the variable name like this **new Date(this.dateString)**
It's giving me a **Invalid Date**

Comment: @aahhhineedhelp, Friendly reminder that we are not here to debug your code, please replace the value of `this.dataString` with the actual string value and then say if it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

```
let momentObject = moment('Fri Aug 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)')
momentObject.add(1,'days');
```

Then to finally get your date object

```
let dateToBeSet = momentObject.toDate();
```

then you can use this dateToBeSet object to do whatever you want

Comment: Using momentjs is not recommended when you can achieve the same result using Vanilla JavaScript.